# python find unique dates from date range for id

Tags: python, date

I have problem that I cannot go through for 4 days. I'am python noobie.
I am working on unix box with python 2.6... and with no additional liberales like numpy, pandas.

What I need to do is to make as small count of lines of below file as possible. So, when dates in date ranges for the same id1, id2 are covering each other they need to be override. But as you can see in expecting output to have min and max of them is not enough, because some of dates are not day after day.

Input

```
ID1|IDTYPE2|20160802|20160912|
ID1|IDTYPE2|20160803|20160913|
ID1|IDTYPE2|20160804|20160914|
ID1|IDTYPE2|20160805|20160915| 
ID1|IDTYPE2|20160808|20160916|
ID1|IDTYPE2|20160925|20160925|
ID2|IDTYPE2|20160925|20160925|
```

Expected Output

```
ID1|IDTYPE2|20160802|20160916|
ID1|IDTYPE2|20160925|20160925|
ID2|IDTYPE2|20160925|20160925|
```

What I have tried, but it gaves me to many results

```
f = open(filename, 'rU')
outf = open(filename + '_date_diff', 'w')
dict_of_ID_dates = defaultdict(list)
for line in f:
  columns = line.split("|")
  ID1 = (columns[0])
  IDType2 = (columns[1])
  start = (columns[2])
  end = (columns[3])
  start_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(start,'%Y%m%d').date()
  end_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(end,'%Y%m%d').date()
  diff = end_date - start_date
  list_of_dates =[]
  date_ranges = range(diff.days +1)
  # [0,1,2,3]
  for date in date_ranges:
    dates = (start_date + datetime.timedelta(date)).isoformat()
# [datetime format dates = '20160101']
    if dates not in dict_of_ID_dates.values():
      dict_of_ID_dates[ID].append(dates)
print (dict_of_ID_dates)
```

Comment: Files are huge like 18 milions of rows when they are already sprited and afregaded to present form. And above I have added where I had stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assume the input file ID and dates always in increasing order. Code below should works.

tmpline acts as a buffer holding line to be append to output when ID changes or current line date1 > date2 in tmpline buffer (means we need to start a new range of dates). Buffer column 2 (date2) will get override if date2 from current line found larger than date2 in buffer.

```
output = []
with open(filename, 'rU') as f:
    prev_id = None
    tmpline = ''
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        (id, date1, date2, dummy) = line.rsplit('|', 3)
        # line = 'ID1|IDTYPE2|20160802|20160912|'
        # id = 'ID1|IDTYPE2'
        # date1 = '20160802'
        # date2 = '20160912'
        # dummy = ''

        # append to output when new ID changes or 
        # date1 > previous date2 (start new range of dates)
        if prev_id != id or date1 > tmpline[2]:
            if tmpline:
               output.append('|'.join(tmpline))
            tmpline = [id, date1, date2, dummy]

        # override end date if larger
        elif date2 > tmpline[2]:
            tmpline[2] = date2
        prev_id = id

    # take care last line
    tmpline = '|'.join(tmpline)
    if tmpline != output[-1]:
        output.append(tmpline)
```

output contains list of lines, print out the to console or can write to another file

```
# print out the ouput
for line in output:
    print line


# based on the input from the post
# output = ['ID1|IDTYPE2|20160802|20160916|', 'ID1|IDTYPE2|20160925|20160925|', 'ID2|IDTYPE2|20160925|20160925|']
```

Comment: Hi Skycc :) Your solution works as I was asking for. But, as I have explain above for @Rodolfo I was only able to check it at home. I will try it at work tomorrow and left update under Rodolfo's commend. Have a nice weekend!

Comment: Ok. Let us know later then. My code should works for both python 2 and 3. Edited some code to take care last line

Comment: OTHER PORTION OF INPUT
ID1|IDTYPE2|20141208|20160606
ID1|IDTYPE2|20141209|20160607
ID1|IDTYPE2|20141210|20160608
ID1|IDTYPE2|20141211|20160609
ID1|IDTYPE2|20141212|20160610
ID1|IDTYPE2|20141215|20160613
ID1|IDTYPE2|20160603|20160603
ID1|IDTYPE2|20160610|20160610
ID1|IDTYPE2|20160617|20160617
ID1|IDTYPE2|20160624|20160624
ID1|IDTYPE2|20160701|20160701

Your CODE OUTPUT
AAVL|SHSO|20141208|20160606
AAVL|SHSO|20160701|20160701

EXPECTED OUTPUT
ID1|IDTYPE2|20141208|20160613
ID1|IDTYPE2|20160617|20160617
ID1|IDTYPE2|20160624|20160624
ID1|IDTYPE2|20160701|20160701

Comment: Hi, Unfortunately it does not work as expected and this is not related to Python versioning but more to code logic. I guess I data sample that I had at home was not enough to run proper test.

Comment: sorry, i have some misunderstanding of what you wanna do, check out the edited answer, hopefully it fits your needs now :)

Comment: wow! it looks like this one gonna work as I would like to :). I will check it on a big file tomorrow. I have only one question. How does 'tmpline = ''' works?

Comment: This one works correctly on big files on Pyton 2.9 So it solve my problem fully.

Comment: You may accept and/or upvote the answer if it fully solve your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

The cool thing about the date format that you are using is that you don't even have to convert it to anything other than string.

It makes it a lot easier, because you can simply say `date1 > date2` and the string comparison works on them!

Having said that you can do this:

```
f = open(filename, 'rU')
ranges = {}
for line in f:
    elem = line.split("|") # get every item of the row in a list

    if elem[0] not in ranges: 
        ranges[elem[0]] = []

    matched = False
    for x in ranges[elem[0]]: # check the current line overlap with any previous ones
        if elem[2] >= x[1] and elem[2] <= x[2] or \
           elem[3] >= x[1] and elem[3] <= x[2] or \
           elem[2] <= x[1] and elem[3] >= x[2] or \
           elem[2] >= x[1] and elem[3] <= x[2]:
            x[1] = min(elem[2], x[1]) # modify the date range 
            x[2] = min(elem[3], x[2]) 
            matched = True
            break

    if not matched: # if it does not overlap add it.
        ranges[elem[0]].append([elem[1], elem[2], elem[3]])

# This is just for display purposes 
for key in ranges.iterkeys():
    for v in ranges[key]:
        print key + '|' + v[0] + '|' + v[1] + '|' + v[2] + '|'
```

Something that you may want to consider though is whether you need the rows in an specific order, if you do you will need to use something other than a dictionary to store the ranges.

Comment: BTW, I could not test it in Python 2.6, let me know if it works.

Comment: Hi Rodolfo :)  I have locked my mind so badly on solution that would compare date ranges, that I would not go through it without help :) Your solution works as I was asking for. Thanks for that! Unfortunately I was able to check only at home, where I have other version of Python than at work. I will check it on Monday and get you know, how it goes. Thanks one more time!